# Anime with the main character falling into a fire pit and holding an amulet that contains his power

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm currently searching for an anime that I have seen in an advert.

In the scene shown, the main character is falling into a fire pit inside a village and holding an amulet. As told in the scene, his power is inside the amulet, and getting it back could kill him. Before completely falling into the fire, he flies up and his eyes glow red.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the ad (or a screenshot)? Where did you see the advert? Can you describe the character in more detail (e.g. was he young, old, blond, dark-haired, handsome, ugly, etc)?